# How can I show an image popup onclick that contains text like Facebook image using Bootstrap and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show a modal pop up window for image. We have a news feed like Facebook. When someone click on the image then it should show a modal window with comments, like, share, tag etc.

Is there any plugin available for this in Bootstrap or Jquery or can any one give link to download source code?

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried and tell us where you're stuck. [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am able to use bootstrap carousel but i am not getting how to use other things like adding text field  , button for like , share e.t.c   on carousel  .

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap modal or other jquery like [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)

if you want to add some custom things like comments,share etc then you should use bootstrap modal because other Jquery may not provide you to add such more custom things so its better that you design your own model !!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It's not free , can you give some other option that's free .

Comment: i'll careful about that @DaImTo

Answer (score 0):

First of all include `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.js`([download](http://getbootstrap.com/)) in your file and then follow the below code,

Now create a link which will launch bootstrap modal on clicking it as

```
<a href="#modal-id" data-toggle="modal">Modal</a>
```

Now define this modal as,

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-id" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
             <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                       <button id="closeModal" type="button" class="close" data- dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button><br>
                  </div>
                  <div class=modal=body>
                       <!--Include anything you want when the popup appears-->
                       <!--Now you can add textboxes as,-->
                       <form>
                            <input type='text' class='form-control'>
                            <button class='btn btn-sm btn-info'>like</button>
                       </form>
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: @user3610792 are you sure you have included the bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css properly in your page?

Comment: Yeah i am sure i have also tried example that is provided on Bootstrap home page , It's also not working.

Comment: @user3610792 did you import jquery.js? If yes then write all the imported files in the '<head>....</head>' section of your page.